# Keyboard properties: What does "Add default action to Menu key" mean?

Tags: keyboard

In the keyboard configuration (gnome-keyboard-properties) under "Behavior of Alt/Windows keys", there is an option "Add default action to the Menu key". What does that even mean, and why isn't it documented anywhere?

(I'm using a German Ubuntu 10.04, so the text in the dialog might be slightly different in English.)

Answer (score 1):

In English it says, "Add the standard behavior to Menu Key. The Menu key is found on the bottom right of most Windows-based laptops, and pulls up the system menu for each application and the desktop. It's usually between the right Alt and Control keys. All that option does is the Menu key to activate the system menu popup, if Ubuntu does not currently have it assigned as such.

I don't know why it's not documented. But now it is!

[image]

Comment: ?? In Fedora KDE the behavior of the key seems to be exactly the same regardless of whether the checkbox in `Keyboard-System Settings` is selected or not. It isn't clear in this post how the behavior in Ubuntu is different when that checkbox is not selected. Does the key do nothing when the option is not selected?